# Python add new column to the beginning of file

Tags: python, csv, dataset

I've been stuck with trying to add a new id column to this dataset in python

```
0000008::Edison Kinetoscopic Record of a Sneeze (1894)::Documentary|Short 
0000010::La sortie des usines Lumière (1895)::Documentary|Short
0000012::The Arrival of a Train (1896)::Documentary|Short
25::The Oxford and Cambridge University Boat Race (1895)::
0000091::Le manoir du diable (1896)::Short|Horror
0000417::Le voyage dans la lune (1902)::Short|Adventure|Fantasy
0000439::The Great Train Robbery (1903)::Short|Action|Crime
0443::Hiawatha, the Messiah of the Ojibway (1903)::
0000628::The Adventures of Dollie (1908)::Action|Short
```

What I what to accomplish is to add a column at the beginning with ids so it looks like this, but I' not quit sure how i would do it. And would love if someone could help me solve it.

```
0::0000008::Edison Kinetoscopic Record of a Sneeze (1894)::Documentary|Short 
1::0000010::La sortie des usines Lumière (1895)::Documentary|Short
2::0000012::The Arrival of a Train (1896)::Documentary|Short
3::25::The Oxford and Cambridge University Boat Race (1895)::
4::0000091::Le manoir du diable (1896)::Short|Horror
5::0000417::Le voyage dans la lune (1902)::Short|Adventure|Fantasy
6::0000439::The Great Train Robbery (1903)::Short|Action|Crime
7::0443::Hiawatha, the Messiah of the Ojibway (1903)::
8::0000628::The Adventures of Dollie (1908)::Action|Short
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input file is called `in_file` and your output file is called `out_file`, you can do something like this within `Python2` or/and `Python3`:

**Python3**

```
data = (k.rstrip() for k in open("in_file", 'r'))
with open("out_file", 'a+') as f:
    for k,v in enumerate(data):            
        f.write("{0}::{1}\n".format(k,v))
```

**Python2**

```
data = (k.rstrip() for k in open("in_file", 'r'))
f = open("out_file", 'a+')
for k,v in enumerate(data):
    f.write("%d::%s\n" % (k,v))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you use a dictionary a list or what, or just concatenate with join
For i in range(dataset):
''.join([i,dataset[i]])

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as a simple for loop over the lines in the existing file.  In each iteration of the loop, I will write the line number, and your delimiter, then print the line read in from the old file.

```
infile = open('original_filename', 'r')
outfile = open('new_filename', 'w')
line_counter = 0
for line in infile:
    outfile.write(str(line_counter) + "::" + line)
    line_counter += 1
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```